# Get network state on each activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am implementing an app who needs an internet connection. If there is no internet connection, a "no connection" message will be displayed on different ways, depending on the activity.

To do this, I have the following class:

```
public class NetworkAvailability {

    private static final String NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_ACTION = "com.toast.NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_ACTION";

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;

    private static NetworkAvailability instance;

    private NetworkAvailability() {
    }

    public static NetworkAvailability getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new NetworkAvailability();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static boolean isAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }

    public void registerNetworkAvailability(final Context context, BroadcastReceiver networkAvailabilityReceiver) {

        context.registerReceiver(networkAvailabilityReceiver, new IntentFilter(NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_ACTION));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            context.registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        } else{
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(true));
                }

                @Override
                public void onLost(Network network) {
                    context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(false));
                }
            };
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback);
            if(isAvailable(context)){
                context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(true));
            } else{
                context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(false));
            }
        }
    }

    public void unregisterNetworkAvailability(Context context, BroadcastReceiver networkAvailabilityReceiver){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver);
        } else{
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
        }
        context.unregisterReceiver(networkAvailabilityReceiver);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver connectivityChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false)) {
                context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(false));
            } else {
                context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(true));
            }
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    private Intent getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(boolean isNetworkAvailable) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, !isNetworkAvailable);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

How can I now use the BroadcastReceiver from each Activity?

Comment: use the broadcast in base activity

Answer (score 0):

What I did was setting the broadcastReceiver on the Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".data.sync.CatchConnectionChangesReceiver"
        android:label="Upload cached images broadcast receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then I have the class:

```
class CatchConnectionChangesReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (Util.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            // Do whatever you want to do when network is available
        }
    }
}
```

The receiver is going to be activated from every activity, you don´t need to register it on each

In Util.isNetworkAvailable() I have the same as in your isAvailable() method

**Update according to first comment**

If you want to do something like:

```
if (isConnected) {
   // Do something here like view.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}
```

You just have your isAvailable() method public, as it´s already static, you can do this from any activity you want:

```
if (NetworkAvailability.isAvailable(this)) {
    // Do something here like view.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}
```

For this last thing you do not need the broadcast receiver

Comment: But how can I do things like: if(!isConnected){noConnectionLayout.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE)} in a specific activity, and if(!isConnected){Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); in another activity?

Comment: This is very helpful, but where do I put the last piece of code if I want to make the test each time the network changes? If I put it in the onCreate() it will be called only one time